# Why do my Vim .vimrc settings not work on Windows

Tags: vim

I made a .vimrc file within the \~\.vim directory using the command: `type NUL > .vimrc` and edited the file with vim.

I put the following settings in my .vimrc file to set up Pathogen and Syntastic as well as some other small settings. These are the settings that I had:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

set number
set tabstop=4
set colorcolumn=110

set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
```

However when I exit and open vim again, my settings don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path to the config file on Windows differs. You can see with `:help .vimrc` what that paths are, it says:

```
"$HOME/_vimrc"     (for MS-DOS and Win32) (*)
"$HOME/vimfiles/vimrc" (for MS-DOS and Win32) (*)
"$VIM/_vimrc"      (for MS-DOS and Win32) (*)

Note: For MS-DOS and Win32, "$HOME" is checked first.  If no
"_vimrc" or ".vimrc" is found there, "$VIM" is tried.
See |$VIM| for when $VIM is not set.
```

This means you should create config file in `C:\Users\YourUserName\_vimrc` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc` (usually in latter case some default `_vimrc` is already exist).